# 'Next Without For' because of extra 'Next'

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting the `Next Without For` compile error on my code because I have an extra `Next` statement. I want the macro to move on to the next column if the value in row 1 is anything but `1`, `2`, or `3`. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
For i = 1 To lastcol
    Select Case Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(1, i).Value
        Case 1
            sPriority = "High"
        Case 2
            sPriority = "Med"
        Case 3
            sPriority = "Low"
        Case Else
            Next i
    End Select
    Set wsTracker = Sheets(sPriority)
    'Omitted code to update data on Priority worksheet with data from Daily Report sheet.
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the same result with an extra If-Then statement:

```
For i = 1 To lastcol
    Select Case Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(1, i).Value
        Case 1
            sPriority = "High"
        Case 2
            sPriority = "Med"
        Case 3
            sPriority = "Low"
    End Select
    If sPriority <> "" Then
        Set wsTracker = Sheets(sPriority)
        'Omitted code to update data on Priority worksheet with data from Daily Report sheet.
    End If
    sPriority = ""
Next i
```

Comment: This way can work, but you will need to assign a zero length string ("" or vbNullString) to sPriority at the beginning of each loop. Or include a Case Else that does so.

Comment: This is probably the clearest method - you can exit a loop early by saying simply "Exit For", but to my knowledge there is no single command to prematurely continue on to the top of the loop without manual intervention some how.

Comment: Makes me wish there was a there was a `Continue For` like in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a little faster:

```
v = Array("High", "Med", "Low")
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To lastcol
    Err.Clear: sPriority = v(Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(1, i) - 1)
    If Err = 0 Then
        Set wsTracker = Sheets(sPriority)
        'Omitted code to update data on Priority worksheet with data from Daily Report sheet.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I don't understand how this code dictates that 1 = high, etc.

Comment: The array `v` holds all of the allowed values for `sPriority`. This array is defined once, before the iteration begins. Then we begin looping through the range which can hold values, of `1` or `2` or `3` or perhaps even something else. We assign `sPriority` to the value associated in the array minus one (this is because the array index begins at 0). This assignment either succeeds or it does not. If it succeeds we have the correct sPriority value. If it fails (because that element index does not exist in the array) then VBA raises an error. We use this outcome to process only if no error.

Answer (score 0):

Although some people hate the use of `GoTo`, I think it would work well in this case:

```
For i = 1 To lastcol
    Select Case Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(1, i).Value
        Case 1
            sPriority = "High"
        Case 2
            sPriority = "Med"
        Case 3
            sPriority = "Low"
        Case Else
            GoTo NextLoop
    End Select
    Set wsTracker = Sheets(sPriority)
    'Omitted code to update data on Priority worksheet with data from Daily Report sheet.
NextLoop:
Next i
```